# importing last row of mysql database in all rows of jtable (Java Swing)

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans

I'm trying to import all of the data from mysql database into a jtable using arraylists but something isn't working right, as i get the number of rows right but they're all values of the last row
Here's the code

```
public ArrayList<medicaments> medicaments_list() {
        ArrayList<medicaments> medicament_lists = new ArrayList<medicaments>();
        String select_nom_type_med = "select * from medicaments where login=?";
        PreparedStatement stmt;
        ResultSet rs2;
        medicaments med;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(select_nom_type_med);
            stmt.setString(1, Utilisateur.getLogin());
            rs2 = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs2.next()) {
                emptytable = false;
                med = new medicaments(rs2.getInt("med_id"), rs2.getString("login"), rs2.getString("med_nom"), rs2.getString("med_type"), rs2.getString("date_debut"), rs2.getString("date_fin"), rs2.getString("frequence"), rs2.getString("temps_1"), rs2.getString("temps_2"), rs2.getString("temps_3"), rs2.getString("temps_4"), rs2.getString("temps_5"), rs2.getString("Stock"), rs2.getString("rappel_stock"));
                medicament_lists.add(med);

            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            System.out.println(e1);

        } catch (SQLException e1) {

            System.out.println(e1);
        }

        return medicament_lists;
    }

    public void populate_jTable_from_db() {
        ArrayList<medicaments> dataarray = medicaments_list();
        model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        model.setRowCount(dataarray.size());
        int row = 0;
        for (medicaments data : dataarray) {
            model.setValueAt(data.get_nom_med(), row, 0);
            model.setValueAt(data.get_type_med(), row, 1);
            row++;
        }
        jTable1.setModel(model);
    }
```

and here's the result :(there's 3 rows in my database and po is the last one i added)
[image]

Comment: Did you add any debug code to display the values of the data as you add it to the TableModel to see what the data is in your ArrayList?

Comment: i just did a JOptionPane in the for loop of dataarray and the values were all the same, but in the while loop of the resultset the values were different, which means the problem is in the arraylist

Comment: in fact, everything was working well until i added another jtable within the same jframe and populated it with another arraylist of the same class, that table gave the exact output but the previous one stopped working.

Comment: *...which means the problem is in the arraylist* -  So the problem is not with the ArrayList itself, but the logic flow of your code and how your create the ArrayList and pass it to another method. And we have no idea on how the ArrayList is created and passed between the two methods, so we can't help. Also, class names should start with an upper case character. Have you ever seen a class in the JDK not start with an upper case character? Learn Java conventions and follow them so the code is highlighted properly in the forum.

Comment: true, the problem was in my medicaments class, i was declaring public static setters and private static attributes, i still don't understand fully the concept of these declarations but i'll be looking to it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your recordset actually contains something and it's what you really want:

```
while (rs2.next()) {
   if (rs2.getString("login").equals(Utilisateur.getLogin())) {
       emptytable = false;
       med = new medicaments(rs2.getInt("med_id"), rs2.getString("login"), 
                             rs2.getString("med_nom"), rs2.getString("med_type"), 
                             rs2.getString("date_debut"), rs2.getString("date_fin"), 
                             rs2.getString("frequence"), rs2.getString("temps_1"), 
                             rs2.getString("temps_2"), rs2.getString("temps_3"), 
                             rs2.getString("temps_4"), rs2.getString("temps_5"), 
                             rs2.getString("Stock"), rs2.getString("rappel_stock"));
        medicament_lists.add(med);
    }
}
```

Comment: i just did a JOptionPane in the for loop of dataarray and the values were all the same, but in the while loop of the resultset the values were different, which means the problem is in the arraylist, in fact, everything was working well until i added another jtable within the same jframe and populated it with another arraylist of the same class, that table gave the exact output but the previous one stopped working.